# Should this have been autodetected as spam?

Tags: bug, spam, spam-detection

A few minutes ago, an answer appeared to one of my questions, blatantly not an answer, but somehow it wasn't detected and filtered by SE itself. Also, the user has been posting this on other questions too. Is this a bug in the spam filters or not meant to be detected?

Screenshot, since it would probably be deleted soon
[image]

Comment: You confuse between spam and random trolling. Those are totally different things, with totally different impact.

Comment: @gnat, you got me!

Comment: Link please, so we can analyze it?

Comment: @tripleee [here you go](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/297639/152859).

Comment: @ShadowWizard There is an email address in there, so it could be spam, or can't it?

Comment: @Patrick still not spam,  as he didn't write anything, plus the email (like the whole post) is nonsense, as it doesn't exist. (no such site as onmicroosoft.com, I can also post "email" like lfhh@bmdlfh.com)

Comment: Yes, there is. It is an Office 365 domain. @Sha (Oh, and there is a typo in the address, but without the typo there is).

Comment: @Patrick https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkmV9.png

Comment: @Sha https://www.whois.com/whois/onmicrosoft.com

Comment: @Patrick different domain. Each letter count. There is also no stackexchangee.com for example. Anyway, doubt Microsoft needs to spam.... they are not *that* desperate. (yet ;))

Comment: As said: I guess that is a typo. @sha

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That doesn't seem to be spam to me, and definitely it doesn't have enough of anything to be detected as spam.

Although we don't know the exact way spam is detected, very obvious spam still gets to the site and is detected by one of the tools built by community members, like SmokeDetector. That image doesn't have any text to match against, and the picture isn't spam either.

I would flag this post as very low quality or abusive.

Comment: Hmmm, but wouldn't it be wise to autodetect answers without any legible words?

Comment: It will definitely end up in the VLQ review queue, but auto-delete it as spam? No.

Comment: Okay then, just confused how this is supposed to work :)

Comment: SPAM = unsolicited advertisement, where do you see any advertisement in the answer?

Comment: Ah, I get it. Perhaps what I meant was we need a troll detecter, which apparently already exists

Comment: Yes, but undisclosed on its working.